# Kubuntu 22.10 Wi-Fi interface randomly disappearing

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, network-manager, iwlwifi

I recently installed Kubuntu 22.10 on my PC as a dual-boot with Windows 11. It's installed on a completely separate SSD. The motherboard is a Asus ROG Strix X670E-E Gaming Wi-Fi.

**Relevant information:**

- *Ubuntu version:* 22.10
- *Kernel:* 5.19.0-23-generic
- *Motherboard Wi-Fi adaptor:* Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210

My Windows 11 install works perfectly as expected after installing the Asus motherboard drivers. However, when I boot into Kubuntu, I'm experiencing an infuriating bug. Initially, the Wi-Fi behaves perfectly. After a random amount of time (so far I've experienced from 4 minutes to 1.5 hours), the PC will stutter for a moment and the Wi-Fi network interface will go down and I'll have no Wi-Fi access. There does not appear to be any specific trigger for this issue and it occurs when I am actively using the PC (including actively using the network connection).

I'm a beginner to Linux so I'm a bit lost as to how to go about debugging and fixing this issue. Here are a few things I've already tried:

- I thought it might have something to do with a power-saving mode issue, so I added this to `etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`:

```
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
options iwlwifi power_save=0
```

- One post that I found recommended adding this to `etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
match-device=driver:wlp9s0
```

**dmesg output immediately after boot finishes**

```
[    7.347765] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    7.417477] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: base HW address: <MAC 'wlp9s0' [IF2]>
[    7.521895] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
[   14.493290] wlp9s0: authenticate with <MAC 'WiFi-E498-5G' [AC38]>
[   14.493300] wlp9s0: Invalid HE elem, Disable HE
[   14.496900] wlp9s0: send auth to <MAC 'WiFi-E498-5G' [AC38]> (try 1/3)
[   14.527876] wlp9s0: authenticated
[   14.528214] wlp9s0: associate with <MAC 'WiFi-E498-5G' [AC38]> (try 1/3)
[   14.529231] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'WiFi-E498-5G' [AC38]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=3)
[   14.532877] wlp9s0: associated
[   14.612824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp9s0: link becomes ready
```

**dmesg output immediately after the issue occurs**

```
[  560.035488] RIP: 0010:iwl_mvm_wait_sta_queues_empty+0xbc/0x110 [iwlmvm]
[  560.035497]  iwl_mvm_mac_flush+0x2bb/0x340 [iwlmvm]
[  560.035679]  ? __iwl_err.cold+0x4f/0x54 [iwlwifi]
[  560.035685]  ? iwl_mvm_recalc_multicast+0x9b/0xb0 [iwlmvm]
[  560.035732] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: iwl_trans_wait_txq_empty bad state = 0
[  560.035738] wlp9s0: failed to remove key (1, <MAC address>) from hardware (-5)
```

Would appreciate any possible assistance as it makes working very difficult since I have to reboot to fix the issue and even then, it comes back relatively quickly. Happy to edit my post and add any additional information/command outputs as required for troubleshooting. Thanks in advance!